# Select the value ONCE from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore, uipickerview

I'm retrieving data from Firestore and I'm inserting it into a pickerview. The problem is that it's inserting everything x2. And I've no idea how to solve that.

So my question is.. How can I make sure the program only retrieve the data ONCE? Instead of plenty of times.

When I run the program the pickerview looks like this:

> Joche
>   Joche
>   Putte
>   Putte
>   Rebecca
>   Rebecca
>   Fredrik
>   Fredrik
>   Anna
>   Anna

Here is the code when retrieving data:

```
func getPerson()
    {
        let authentication = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        db.collection("users").document(authentication!).collection("person").getDocuments { (QuerySnapshot, err) in

            //If error is not equal to nil
            if err != nil
            {
                print("Error getting documents: \(String(describing: err))");
            }
                //Succeded
            else
            {
                //For-loop
                for elem in QuerySnapshot!.documents
                {
                    let data = elem.data()

                    data.forEach { (item) in
                        if let person1Data = data["name"] as? String
                        {
                            self.personArray.append(person1Data)
                        }
                    }
                }
                self.pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
            }
        }
    }
```

So how can I make sure it will only store the value once?

Comment: `if let person1Data = item["name"] as? String` ??

Comment: You're getting `data["name"]` while iterating over all keys in `data`. Just drop `data.forEach`

Comment: @user28434 Can you post that as an answer with a snippet of code?

Comment: @user28434 That worked great! Can you make an answer of it?

Comment: Sidenote: make use of conditional unwrapping, such as `if let error = error { ... }` instead of all that force unwrapping.